Quill rich text editor not keeping font size on copy/paste
I am using the Quill rich text editor V2.0 on an xhtml page via Javascript. When I copy and paste text from MS word to the editor the font size is lost, this also happens on the demo on https://quilljs.com/
I investigated and found that when I paste text from Word with a font size applied it looks like this
<p style="margin: 0in 0in 8pt; line-height: 107%; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Aptos, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 24.0pt; line-height: 107%;">Test 24</span></p>

but when I paste it to Quill it looks like this
<p>Test 24</p>

My guess is either the <span tag is removed when its within a <p tag on paste or everything in the <p tag is removed on paste.
Is there a way to keep all the details on paste or not lose font size when pasting?

I don't think any WYSIWYG editor can preserve all the pasted styles because allowing this would require the editor to properly parse and "understand" them and incorporate them into its own document structure.
Your best bet would be to intercept the paste action, parse the pasted content, and make the changes you like before passing the content to Quill. Something like this https://billauer.co.il/blog/2021/12/quill-mixed-paste-format/

Using custom StyleAttributor from parchment fixes this issue for me. Inline styles are now rendered.
import { StyleAttributor, Scope, type LeafBlot } from 'parchment';

export const SizeStyle = new StyleAttributor('size', 'font-size', { scope: Scope.INLINE });
export const WidthStyle = new StyleAttributor('width', 'width', { scope: Scope.INLINE });
export const HeightStyle = new StyleAttributor('height', 'height', { scope: Scope.INLINE });
export const FontWeight = new StyleAttributor('font-weight', 'font-weight', { scope: Scope.INLINE });
...
Quill.register(FontWeight, true);
Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);
Quill.register(HeightStyle, true);
Quill.register(WidthStyle, true);

